# If url ends with double dash, want to rewrite(Apache)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

If url ends with double dash or hyphen(--), I need to redirect to some internal page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} --$
RewriteRule .* /error
```

**www.mySite.com/myPage--** will be **www.mySite.com/error**

But it's not working. Is there any wrong with this code?

I think this is because it deals with special character not string.

*edit.

This is my whole `vhost.conf`.

```
ServerName mysite.com
DocumentRoot "/myWebRoot/"

ErrorDocument 400 /jsp/errorHandler.jsp
ErrorDocument 403 /jsp/errorHandler.jsp
ErrorDocument 404 /jsp/errorHandler.jsp
ErrorDocument 500 /jsp/errorHandler.jsp
ErrorDocument 503 /jsp/errorHandler.jsp

RedirectMatch --$ /jsp/errorHandler.jsp


<IfModule mod_jk.c>
    JkMount /*.jsp          mysite
    JkMount /*.do           mysite
    JkMount /*.page         mysite
    JkMount /*.json         mysite
    JkMount /servlet/*      mysite
</IfModule>

<LocationMatch "/servlet/*">
    SetHandler jakarta-servlet
    SetEnv     JK_WORKER_NAME mysite
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "/*\.(do$|jsp$)">
    SetHandler jakarta-servlet
    SetEnv     JK_WORKER_NAME mysite
</LocationMatch>

    # BEGIN Expire headers
    <ifModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
......

    </ifModule>
    # END Expire headers

    # BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>

      <LocationMatch "\.(json)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      </LocationMatch>
      <LocationMatch "\.(do)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=8640000, public, must-revalidate"
      </LocationMatch>
      <LocationMatch "/*/header.jsp">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      </LocationMatch>
    </ifModule>
    # END Cache-Control Headers

    <Directory "/myWebRoot/">
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride none
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all 
            Deny from env=go_out
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule --$ /error
```

If you want an actual redirect, you could use:

```
RedirectMatch --$ /error
```

Comment: "not working" tells me nothing.  Is this in a .htaccess file or in your virtualhost configuration?  Do you have other RewriteRules in place that might interfere?

Comment: It is my virtualhost config.(vhost.conf) I will add my whole config code to question. And it seems to me nothing will interfere with the RewriteRules.